# mod rewrite remove www and turn %2520 into space

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Redirecting www to non is working fine, but turning all occurrences of %2520 to a space, using QUERY_STRING seems to fail when I combine them.
I've Googled and SOed loads of combining RewriteCond and RewriteRule but I can't find an example that even seems close to how this one works. All I've worked out is that I'm probably abusing the (.*) regex. Total regex and mod_rewrite noob here - no snide comments please :-) Thanks in advance!

I've tried this, and the reverse:

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) ^www.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(%2520)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?%1\ %3 [N,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

An url has a limited subset of characters it allows. Spaces are not allowed as a character in an url, and therefore they are encoded to `%20`. Similary, `%2520` is a double encoded space.

The rule you provide works fine for me (you could leave out the capturing group around `%2520` as it is unnecessary, but it doesn't break anything). It will transform `http://example.com/minimalonecharacter?asdf%2520qwer` to `http://example.com/minimalonecharacter?asdf%20qwer`.

I notice that you use status code `301` (permanent redirect) for this. I recommend *not* testing with a permanent redirect, until everything works as you want it to work. The browser might cache a permanent redirect, skipping a request to the server. If you make a wrong rewriterule, this result is cached and future attempts "strangely" point to your first attempt.

Comment: Unfortuntely: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1?%1(%20)%3 [N,R=301] Still doesn't work, as my rules wont combine. it ignores the last two statements of the four. and anyway I got the last two rules from a working example. Does someone know how to make both the first two, and last two work together?