# Redirect one page with a query string to another page using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

having issues redirecting from an existing page to another page. I have the URL:

```
http://www.thedomain.com/webpage-themission.php?wp=The%20Mission
```

and I want to redirect it to:

```
http://www.thedomain.com/webpage.php?wp=The%20Mission
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/webpage-themission.php?wp=The%20Mission$ http://thedomain.com/webpage.php?wp=The%20Mission$1 [L,R=301]
```

and many other combinations but no such luck, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the query string in the redirect rule, as it is not evaluated at all.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?webpage-themission\.php$ http://thedomain.com/webpage.php [L,R=301,QSA]
```

A few notes:

- It is important to note the `QSA` flag that is specified.  This will have the effect of appending the query string `wp=The%20Mission` to the redirected URL.
- I also escaped the `.` in the matching rule so that it does not behave as a wildcard and allow a redirect on something like `/webpage-themissionXphp`
- I put the `?` after the initial backslash, as typically in directory context (i.e. .htaccess) the forward slash is not compared, meaning that the rule would need to be `^webpage...`.  Putting `/?` makes the rule work in both the directory context and the server context (i.e. httpd.conf).

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for that, I've given it a shot but nothing has happened. The query string is important as it determines what content to pull out for any given page (old school site)
The webpage-themission.php and webpage.php are templates used. Just to give more info.

Comment: @AkiraDawson The query string would be passed along with the rewrite when using the `QSA` flag.  Are you sure that you have AllowOverride properly specified for this directory such that the `.htaccess` file is even utilized?

Comment: Oh no, i'm getting something now, the result is now
http://thedomain.com/webpage.php?wp=the%2520Mission
Where is that %25 coming from?

Sorry, didn't see that you made edits to your answer before hand. That explains the confusion!

Comment: @AkiraDawson Unfortunately, you are running into a double-encoding issue where the `%` is being encoded to `%25` on redirect.  You may actually need to inspect the query string and fix the space.  Check out this question for help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012017/mod-rewrite-remove-www-and-turn-2520-into-space  The best solution is simply to avoid putting characters which require urlencoding into your URI or query strings to being with.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, I ended up getting it working by changing [L,R=301,QSA] to [L,R=301,QSA,NE,N] and the redirect is now working. the I don't have that double encoding issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this to your .htaccess file

```
Redirect 301 http://www.thedomain.com/webpage-themission.php?wp=The%20Mission http://www.thedomain.com/webpage.php?wp=The%20Mission
```